# SQL Developer importing csv row limit

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've got around 500 csv files, I've merged them into one big csv file - ~10gb and 10mln rows. I've got a local database, I'm importing data through sql developer, after successful import rows available are only ~3.8mln.
Has anyone got an idea why I've got this loss of data? I've checked all csv, everything is ok with them.

Comment: Any log file? What does it say?

Comment: For FAT32 the maximum file size is 4GB, could be somehow related to that maybe?